# Open link in background tab without losing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, focus

I made a modal popup that reveals coupon code on my website, and the button is linked to the offer page. I want the offer page to open in background tab without losing focus on my page. is there any way to do it? here is the working [link](https://www.pmbypm.com/best-pmp-exam-simulator/) for my modal popup on button *reveal coupon code and buy*, thank you.

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
  alert("Text Copied");
}
```

```css
.coup-button {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #dc3545;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.coup-button:hover {
  border: #dc3545 solid;
  color:#dc3545;
  background: #fff;
}

.coup-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.coup-overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.coup-popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.coup-popup h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
}
.coup-popup .coup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.coup-popup .coup-close:hover {
  color: #dc3545;
}
.coup-popup .coup-content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.coup-copybutton{width: auto; height: auto; background: #dc3545; color: white; border: none;cursor: pointer; border-radius: 8px; outline: none; padding:10px; box-sizing: border-box;}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .coup-popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="coup-button" href="https://www.pmbypm.com/best-pmp-exam-simulator/" target="_blank" onclick="location.href='#popup1'">Reveal Coupon Code</a>
<div id="popup1" class="coup-overlay">
 <div class="coup-popup">
  <h4>Here is your Coupon Code</h4>
  <a class="coup-close" href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="coup-content" style="text-align: center;">
   <p id="p1"><strong>UDEMYPM30</strong></p>
   <button class="coup-copybutton" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy Text</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you are trying to open new tab in background, right?

Comment: yes, just like you open link while holding *ctrl* key

Comment: I don't think it's possible, not in all browsers and not today. Opening new tab in background would result in user not noticing it. Think about how many (performance or security) problems this would cause. Some nasty websites used to open few tabs of ads in background with which you had to deal later. There are many reasons to not go that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.open('link', 'name');`

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
  alert("Text Copied");
}

function openView() {
  location.href='#popup1';
  window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60432716/', 'name'); 
}
```

```css
.coup-button {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #dc3545;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.coup-button:hover {
  border: #dc3545 solid;
  color:#dc3545;
  background: #fff;
}

.coup-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.coup-overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.coup-popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.coup-popup h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
}
.coup-popup .coup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.coup-popup .coup-close:hover {
  color: #dc3545;
}
.coup-popup .coup-content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.coup-copybutton{width: auto; height: auto; background: #dc3545; color: white; border: none;cursor: pointer; border-radius: 8px; outline: none; padding:10px; box-sizing: border-box;}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .coup-popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="coup-button" href="https://www.pmbypm.com/best-pmp-exam-simulator/" target="_blank" onclick="openView()">Reveal Coupon Code</a>
<div id="popup1" class="coup-overlay">
 <div class="coup-popup">
  <h4>Here is your Coupon Code</h4>
  <a class="coup-close" href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="coup-content" style="text-align: center;">
   <p id="p1"><strong>UDEMYPM30</strong></p>
   <button class="coup-copybutton" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy Text</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```